# can't scale only at Z

Tags: scale

I cant scale the Z[image]
but at X and Y it still works fine
it made from extruding cylinder and try to scale down the Z from 3 edge
sorry for bad english, im also new

Comment: As InTheBeef explains, it's already flat on the Z axis, so what are you trying to do exactly? Maybe show with a drawing?

Answer (score 0):

You can't scale Z when the selection is already scaled to Z = 0 (they are equal position and you are using Median point pivot). You'll have to manually create a different in Z between them to be able to scale, otherwise use a different pivot point.

Comment: ive tried another pivot point but nothing. how do i make the another different in Z, is it like make a loop cut near the selection?

Comment: No? It's the coordinates of the vertex. Z is up & down by default, the median point being the median of all those points.  If you move one vertex up, the median would be inbetween them with a gap that you could scale along Z